# Create a Button Identical to Facebook SDK's `LoginButton` or Override LoginButton's OnClick

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-button

I need to override the Facebook `LoginButton`'s default behaviour and run custom login code as I'm use the `Parse` SDK.

Ideally I would use the `com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton` as this looks exactly how I want it to look however you can't override the click event and I don't want to use the built in login behaviour. I have seen a question about downloading the SDK and making the LoginButton's OnClick public, however I am compiling the SDK as a gradle dependency, therefore I don't have access to modify the source code.

This is why I am having to create a custom `Button`. So far I am able to set the background of the button like so:

```
android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_button_background"
```

However this doesn't put the little Facebook logo to the left of the text. I know the resource value of it is `com_facebook_button_icon` I just don't know how to get it in the `Button`.

**MY QUESTIONS**

1. How do I get the little Facebook icon in my `Button`?
2. Is it possible to override the LoginButton's OnClick other than downloading and modifying the SDK's code? If so how?

Answer (score 2):

You can override the `onClick` of your `LoginButton` on the `onViewCreated()` of your fragment or on the `onPostCreate()` of your activity:

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Your custom action using Parse
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a custom button's background you must use it as:

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />`
```

`

Comment: then use an imagebutton and use facebook login button's image as background

Comment: _“I don't want the default behaviour to occur when you click it”_ – why not? What do you want to do different from “normal” login?

Comment: I need to link it to an account on our system. I am using the Parse SDK.

Answer (score 0):

In android SDk 4.0+ You can add your Full functionality custom button 
1.

> You Neeed to add Relative OR Frame Layout bY make facebook button visiblity gone and not add facebook xmlns in main layout your xml should like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<TextView android:text="Login With Facebook"

    android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" /></RelativeLayout>
```

2.

> Initialize Facebbok sdk and callback like

```
  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

3.

> then do what you do with assign callback to facebook button

```
  login_button.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {


                            try {Log.e("REsponse",response+"");
                                Log.e("OBJECT",object+"");
                              id = loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId().toString();
                                Log.e("FBId", id);
                                 AuthToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken().toString();
                                Log.e("Auth", AuthToken);
                                URL profile_pic = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large");
                                Log.e("profile_pic",
                                        profile_pic + "");
                                email = response.getJSONObject().getString("email");
                                Log.e("email->",email);

                                Name =object.getString("name").toString();//("firstname");
                                 Log.e("Name->",Name);
                                LastName = response.getJSONObject().getString("last_name");
                                Gender = response.getJSONObject().getString("gender");
                              //  email = response.getJSONObject().getString("email");
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this,email,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                Log.e("LastName->",LastName);
                                Log.e("Gender->",Gender);
                                Log.e("Auth", AuthToken);
                                Log.e("FBId", id);
                                Log.e("profile_pic", profile_pic.getPath().toString()+"-->");

                            } catch (org.json.JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.e("E->",e+"");
                            }
                            catch (MalformedURLException e)
                            {
                                Log.e("E->",e+"");
                            }
                            // Application code
                            //       Log.v("LoginActivity", response());
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
           // Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,Home.class);
            Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Welcome"+Firstname,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //startActivity(intent);
            Log.e("Name-***********>",Name);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // code for cancellation
            Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Cancle Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            //  code to handle error
            Toast.makeText(Login.this,exception+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

4.

**

> Now Come the main logic Whatever Ui instace you have put with Fb login button in relative or frame layout assign Onclick for it In my case i have use
>   Textview so its like

**

```
  TextView  btnLogin= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new
                                        View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                                loginButton.performClick();
                                                loginButton.setPressed(true);

                                            }
                                        });
```

Chees! i have test it it work like butter enjoy!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
<button style="background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logotypes/32/square-facebook-16.png)no-repeat;width:100px;height:20px;">Submit</button>
```

I guess i am getting you right....

Comment: It's Android I'm afraid